# Check two different dataframes with different number of rows and then apply operation

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes df1 and df2 with different total number of rows.
I need to check which elements of the first column of df1 exist in the first column of df2. When there is a match, then I need to perform an operation between column 2 of df1 and df2.
Example:

```
DF1      

col1   col2   
name1  value1 
name2  value2 
...    ...
nameN  valueN   

DF2
col1   col2   
name1  value1 
name2  value2 
...    ...
nameM  valueM
```

If DF1[nameX] == DF2[nameY] then `my_value = DF1[valueX] - DF2[valueY]`.
I managed to understand how to check whether the nameX and nameY are the same (I used `isin()`) but then I have problems understanding how to tell to calculate `my_value` iteratively if the condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

You may try that:

```
for el1, el2 in zip(df1["col1"], df2["col1"]):
  if el1 == el2: 
    my_value = el1-el2
    print(my_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the match for 1st two column

```
match = df1.isin(df2)['col1']
match = match[match == True].index
```

do the operation according to match

```
df1.loc[match]['col2'] - df2.loc[match]['col2']
```